# What is the update status of "The Legendary Moonlight Sculptor" webtoon in 2019?

Tags: moonlight-sculptor

I have recently read all chapters of *The Legendary Moonlight Sculptor*, but it seems like it didn't end yet.

When will the webtoon have any update?

Comment: while it wont matter now that the user's profile is deleted, for future reference [*"Close voters aren't expected to know whether announcements have been made. Almost any "Will X get an anime adaptation" question falls in this category, even if the answer is already known."*](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3863/1587). as @Dimitrimx has pointed out that there is announced news, i am voting to reopen

Answer (score 1):

Yes, LMS will soon start the release of season 3.

Originally season 3 would start in early 2019, however delays have been announced. The author had an accident, and hurt his arm. Leading to a new writer, and the team taking the chance to make some changes to the characters etc. Hence the series will start again in late 2019 instead, with the earliest indicator being October.

All though I can't find the original Korean post anymore, here is the translated edition of the [Writen apology by LMS](https://the-legendary-moonlight-sculptor.fandom.com/wiki/LMS_Webtoon_-_Apology_for_the_Delay)

**Edit**
LMS has since 30-09-2019 released a new chapter, officially kicking off season 3.